# How to create file field instance that allow teaser and full description and not allowed extensions but denied extensions?

Tags: 7, entities, files

I need to change the default Drupal functionality of file field:

- I want to be able to allow upload of all files types, EXCEPT the extensions listed (reversing the current funcitonality)
- I also want to be able to add a teaser field and a description field to the file.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to think about re-phrasing/re-writing this.  I can't make much sense out of it.

Comment: it's better now?

Comment: There we go :-)

Answer (score 1):

The second part of your question is easy with the [File Entity](http://drupal.org/project/file_entity) module - it turns file uploads into fieldable entities, so adding your teaser/description field is just like adding a field anywhere else in Drupal (make you sure you read the README file - it's not overly clear at first).  The module is also on an unstable release, but Dave Reid is pretty damn awesome so I can't imagine it'll be that way for long :-)

Off the top of my head, I can't think of an answer to the first part though I'm afraid.

**EDIT**

There's an issue [here](http://drupal.org/node/997900) that has a couple of patches for Core that give you a radio box to either *Allow only these file types* or *Allow everything EXCEPT these file types*.  I've not tested the patches as I don't really want to patch Core for something that I personally don't need, but definitely give it a read!